# How to recreate the animation exactly similar to iOS 7 calendar

Tags: ios7, calendar

I want to recreate the animation exactly similar to iOS 7 calendar. You can see the animation here: http://vimeo.com/69247779

Also I have seen Session 218 video from WWDC 2013.
Not getting how to use Layout-to-Layout transition in this.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.